# Is there any way to speed this code up? Too many fopen()'s

Tags: php, fopen

```
foreach($streams as $stream) {
    parse_str($stream, $data);
    if(stripos($data['type'], $format) !== false && stripos($data['quality'], 'small') !== false) {
        $video = fopen($data['url'] . '&signature='.$data['sig'], 'r');
        $file = fopen($_GET['id'] . '.flv', 'w');
        stream_copy_to_stream($video, $file);
        fclose($video);
        fclose($file);
        echo echo_video($id);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I am making a YouTube downloader and for some reason, the conversion (of the smallest quality) is so small, that my server times out. Is there a way to replace these `fopen()`'s with `file_put_contents()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can act as a URL proxy instead of first downloading the file then serving it. As you download and serve the data on the fly, you can also write the content on your local server in a file or as a BLOB in a database. Moreover, you can increase the timeout limit to avoid timing out.

Comment: I increased the timeout. How can I do the first thing that you said? Sounds interesting.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619557/streaming-output-to-a-file-and-the-browser for example code.

Comment: Would I need to send headers?

Comment: Yes, to indicate the type and size of the file.